# BitmapFactory returns null

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap

I am working on an application where I am getting an image from the web server.

I need to save that image in a sqlite database.  Maybe it will be saved in a `byte[]`; I have done this way, taking the datatype as `blob`, and then retrieving the image from db and showing at imageview.

I am stuck somewhere, however:  I am getting `null` when I decodefrom bytearray

The code I have used is:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    URL url = null;                              
    url = new URL(http://....);
    URLConnection ucon = null;
    ucon = url.openConnection();    
    is = ucon.getInputStream();
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {                                    
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {                                  
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
ByteArrayBuffer barb = new ByteArrayBuffer(128);
int current = 0;
try {
    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
    barb.append((byte) current);
} catch (IOException e) {                                   
    e.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] imageData = barb.toByteArray();
```

Then I have inserted imageData in to the db..

To retrieve the image:

```
byte[] logo = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("Logo_Image"));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(logo, 0, logo.length);
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But I am getting the error:

> Bitmap bitmap is getting null.

Comment: Does byte[] logo contain any data after c.getBlob()?

Comment: @sandstar: yes byte[] logo contains data like- [35,86,56,85,13,78].

Comment: ByteArrayBuffer is no longer available in Java so part of this solution is now obsolete which is why I am trying https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138739/bytearraybuffer-missing-in-sdk23

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, It happens, when your byte[] not decode properly after retrieving from database as blob type.

So, You can do like this way, **Encode - Decode**,

Encode the image before writing to the database:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, THUMB_QUALITY, outputStream);
mByteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();  // write this to database as blob
```

And then decode it like the from Cursor:

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cursor.getBlob(columnIndex));
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

Also, If this not work in your case, then I suggest you to go on feasible way..

- Make a directory on external / internal storage for your application
  images.
- Now store images on that directory.
- And store the path of those image files in your database. So you
  don't have a problem on encoding-decoding of images.