# ByteArrayBuffer missing in SDK23

Tags: android

when updating android SDK 22->23 `org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer` is not there anymore - is there a replacement or is this a bug?

Comment: Basically, all of HttpClient was removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From javadoc:

> This class was deprecated in API level 22.
>
> Please use `openConnection()` instead. Please visit this [webpage](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) for further details.

Answer (score 38):

this answer can be a bit late, but an alternative is to replace *ByteArrayBuffer* with *ByteArrayOutputStream* and use an array of bytes as follows:

Example of code with ByteArraybuffer:

```
   BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
   ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
   while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
   }
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(buffer.toByteArray());
```

Now, using with *ByteArrayOutputStream*:

```
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
     ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     //We create an array of bytes
     byte[] data = new byte[50];
     int current = 0;

     while((current = bis.read(data,0,data.length)) != -1){
           buffer.write(data,0,current);
     }

     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
     fos.write(buffer.toByteArray());
     fos.close();
```

Well, I hope this be useful.