# Cannot resolve symbol 'ByteArrayBuffer'

Tags: java, android

So, in my app there's a WebView with an image that I want to save on button click. 
To do this I used this code:

```
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

 public void DownloadFromUrl(String fileName) {  //this is the downloader method
    try {
            URL url = new URL(wv2.getUrl()); //you can write here any link
            File file = new File(fileName);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            wv2.draw(canvas );

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download begining");
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download url:" + url);
            Log.d("ImageManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download ready in"
                            + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                            + " sec");

    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
    }
```

}

Where `wv2` is WebView. Oddly I can't do this anymore, and I get an error `Cannot resolve symbol 'ByteArrayBuffer'` in my import statement

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138739/bytearraybuffer-missing-in-sdk23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138739/bytearraybuffer-missing-in-sdk23)

Comment: Yes, I've seen the question. But the image WebView contains is not a site or image from link, it's a picture it gets from camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

org.apache.http is removed in the lastests SDK, that's why your import fails.

NB you don't need ByteArrayBuffer in this code, you could use a ByteBuffer instead, or write from `bis` to `fos` like so:

```
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    fos.write(current);
            }

            fos.close();
```

Comment: Replacing `ByteArrayBuffer` with `ByteBuffer` still leaves me with the same error. So how should I replace the insides of `public void` above? I'd be greateful for any alternative or tutorial

Comment: Did you remove the ByteArrayBuffer import (remplacing it by a ByteBuffer import) ?

Comment: yes, with `import org.apache.http.util.ByteBuffer;`

Comment: ByteBuffer is not a part of org.apache.http (that's the point).
Try `import java.nio.ByteBuffer;`

Comment: You could also write directly the result of `bis.read()` to `fos`.